# migrating visual studio project from 2012 to 2017 errors CL.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, cl.exe

I run windows 7 with visual studio 2012. Everything compile fine.
I open the same project on the new visual studio 2017 community, i got a popup saying to upgrade to windows sdk 10 and toolset v141. I did.

Then when building i got this?

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(361,5):
>   error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741701.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: -1073741701 = 0xC000 007B, which is the windows INVALID_NAME error. Double check your program names and file paths are legal.

Comment: And that you have the correct write privileges https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024268/msbuild-error-msb6006-cmd-exe-exited-with-code-1

Comment: Try compiling with v140 and SDK 8.1in VS 2015 .It should work. Did you uninstall vs2012 before installing vs2017, looks like the  path to the latest cl.exe may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your support, i found the answer.
I installed VS 2017 community without uninstalling VS 2012 first and it gave me toolset problem with CL.exe. The solution is to uninstall VS 2012 and then repair VS 2017.